# bulk en golang , cambio de tipo de variables

Tags: go

No se mucho de golang y quería cambiar el tipo de las variables por ítems en este código de un bulk. ¿Cómo se haría?

```
    var bulk [][]string
    var bulkKeys []string
    adding := 0
    index := 0
    if len(keys)%limit != 0 {
        adding++
    }
    for len(bulk) != (len(keys)/limit + adding) {
        bulkKeys = make([]string, 0)
        for i := index; i < len(keys); i++ {
            if len(bulkKeys) == limit {
                index = i
                break
            }
            bulkKeys = append(bulkKeys, keys[i])
        }
        bulk = append(bulk, bulkKeys)
    }
    return bulk
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cambiar el tipo de variable por items? ¿qué significa eso? ¿podrías explayarte? No se entiende muy bien qué querés hacer.

Comment: Me adhiero a lo que dice @kvothe838 de que no se entiende muy bien qué querés hacer.
De todas maneras intuyo que no quieres tener un typo de datos string sino un tipo propio de datos llamado Item, si es esto lo que quieres debes definirte un struct y utilizar este struct como el tipo de tus slices.